# Did Tamerlane express the desire to rebuild the empire of Genghis Khan?

Tags: history

[This](https://owlcation.com/humanities/40-Facts-about-Tamerlane-Timur-the-Lame) site says:

> Tamerlane’s ambition was to rebuild the empire of Genghis Khan, who had died a century earlier.

A similar claim is posted in [this](http://factslegend.org/15-facts-tamerlanes-curse/) site:

> Timur’s sole motive was to rebuild the empire that was once built by the barbarous Genghis Khan but in an attempt to do so, he ended but building the Timurid Dynasty.

Did Tamerlane express the desire to rebuild the empire of Genghis Khan?

Comment: You'll probably get better answers on History.SE.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have found my answer in a JSTOR document. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. According to this [journal](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25183464?seq=5#page_scan_tab_contents), Timur presented himself as the restorer of Chinggisid rights and laid claims over the whole of the former Mongol Empire.

[image]